# How to use querySelectorAll only for elements that have a specific attribute set?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

I'm trying to use `document.querySelectorAll` for all checkboxes that have the `value` attribute set.

There are other checkboxes on the page that do not have `value` set, and the value is different for each checkbox. The ids and names are not unique though.

Example:
    `<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="c2" value="DE039230952"/>`

How do I select just those checkboxes that have values set?

Comment: does this include blanks? like `values=""`

Comment: the other checkboxes have no value at all so it wouldn't have to include that.

Answer (score 353, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` like this:

```
var test = document.querySelectorAll('input[value][type="checkbox"]:not([value=""])');
```

This translates to:

> get all inputs with the attribute "value" and has the attribute "value" that is not blank.

[In this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfm2G/1/), it disables the checkbox with a non-blank value.

Comment: How to select only checkbox type inputs though? there are lots of other input tags that have value attributes, but I only want the checkboxes.

Comment: @Soryn add `[type="checkbox"]`. Updated my answer.

Comment: GREAT ANSWER! This eliminates largely the need for including jQuery in mini libraries for DOM traversal. I've got some extra tips in an answer below.

Comment: could you tell me what is this syntax input[value][type="checkbox"]:not([value=""] i didnt see this syntax like this before in javascript

Comment: @blackHawk The syntax uses CSS Selectors. As specified by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) it "is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas". You can read about CSS Selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 69):

With your example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="c2" value="DE039230952"/>
```

Replace $$ with document.querySelectorAll in the examples:

```
$$('input') //Every input
$$('[id]') //Every element with id
$$('[id="c2"]') //Every element with id="c2"
$$('input,[id]') //Every input + every element with id
$$('input[id]') //Every input including id
$$('input[id="c2"]') //Every input including id="c2"
$$('input#c2') //Every input including id="c2" (same as above)
$$('input#c2[value="DE039230952"]') //Every input including id="c2" and value="DE039230952"
$$('input#c2[value^="DE039"]') //Every input including id="c2" and value has content starting with DE039
$$('input#c2[value$="0952"]') //Every input including id="c2" and value has content ending with 0952
$$('input#c2[value*="39230"]') //Every input including id="c2" and value has content including 39230
```

Use the examples above directly, without the need for additional library, just by adding:

```
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

Some additions:

```
$$(.) //The same as $([class])
$$(div > input) //div is parent tag to input
document.querySelector() //equals to $$()[0] or $()
```

Answer (score 28):

**Extra Tips:**

Multiple "nots", input that is NOT hidden and NOT disabled:

```
:not([type="hidden"]):not([disabled])
```

Also did you know you can do this:

```
node.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div');
```

This is equivelent to jQuery's:

```
$(node).parent().find('div');
```

Which will effectively find all divs in "node" and below recursively, HOT DAMN!