# Does an Inverse querySelector exist?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I know I can can use querySelector to locate an element in a document

```
var element = document.querySelector(".myclass")
```

but does there exist a inverse querySelector such that:

```
var selector = document.inverseQuerySelector(element);
Assert.AreEqual(element, document.querySelector(selector));
```

the returned selector of inverseQuerySelector always uniquely identifies the specified element?

Comment: Try "not:", as shown briefly in this questions answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777684/how-to-use-queryselectorall-only-for-elements-that-have-a-specific-attribute-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there are many selectors (probably infinite) that can select the same element.

For a function to be inversable (even in math), it's mapping has to be 1 to 1, this is not the case.

BTW, Because of that, you could create some that may work only **in some cases**. For example:

```
function inverseForElementWithUniqueId(element){
   return '#' + element.id;
}

var selector = inverseForElementWithUniqueId(element);
Assert.AreEqual(element, document.querySelector(selector));   //True
```

(code which indeed may look trivial)

But as said, because of the theory, this would work only in a subset of the cases.

But, it would work only sometimes

Comment: Perhaps inverseQuerySelector was a bad name. I guess all I'm after is it possible to generate a selector that uniquely identifies a given element in a document, and not the inverse of any possible selector.

Comment: Given that, I extended the answer

Comment: You could build an entire query based on classes, id, and dom position, but I don't see how that'd benefit

Answer (score 4):

**You can create one that can work in all cases**. In two ways:

1. Using **nth-child** ( which is using index)

The solution is the following:

```
function getMyPathByIndex(element){

        if(element == null)
            return '';

        if(element.parentElement == null)
            return 'html'

        return getMyPathByIndex(element.parentElement) + '>' + ':nth-child(' + getMyIndex(element) + ')';

    }

function getMyIndex(element){

        if(element == null)
            return -1;
        if(element.parentElement == null)
            return 0;

        let parent = element.parentElement;

        for(var index = 0; index < parent.childElementCount; index++)
            if(parent.children[index] == element)
                return index + 1;

}
```

For instance, **the element**:

```
<a id="y" class="vote-up-off" title="This answer is useful">up vote</a>
```

You can get this element in this page **just by typing in the console:**

```
document.querySelector('a[title="This answer is useful"]');
```

has it **unique querySelector**:

> html>:nth-child(2)>:nth-child(5)>:nth-child(1)>:nth-child(1)>:nth-child(3)>:nth-child(2)>:nth-child(6)>:nth-child(1)>:nth-child(1)>:nth-child(1)>:nth-child(1)>:nth-child(1)>:nth-child(2)

2. Using **attributes for a "human readable" way**:

   1. Get the attributes of the elements ( only the explicit attributes).
   2. Get the entire path to the element.
   3. Use the multiple attribute selector to unify all the features.

Using the same elemen before has it **unique querySelector**:

> html>body>div>div>div>div>div>div>table>tbody>tr>td>div>a[id="y"][class="vote-up-off"][title="This
>   answer is useful"]

**test if the solution is the correct** by:

```
// e is an element and e must exist inside the page
document.querySelector( getMyPathByIndex(e)) === e && 
document.querySelectorAll( getMyPathByIndex(e)).length === 1
```

**The code solutions is the follow:**

```
function convertAttributesToQuerySelector(element){

  var tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
  var result = tagName;   

  Array.prototype.slice.call(element.attributes).forEach( function(item) {
  if(element.outerHTML.contains(item.name))
    result += '[' + item.name +'="' + item.value + '"]';

});

  return result;
  //["a[id="y"]", "a[class="vote-up-off"]", "a[title="This answer is useful"]"]

}

function getMyPath(element){

   if(element.parentElement.tagName == 'HTML')
    return 'html';

  return  getMyPath(element.parentElement) + '>' + element.parentElement.tagName.toLowerCase() ;
  //"html>body>div>div>div>div>div>div>table>tbody>tr>td>div"

}

function myUniqueQuerySelector(element){

  var elementPath = getMyPath(element);
  var simpleSelector =   convertAttributesToQuerySelector(element);

  return elementPath + '>' + simpleSelector;

}
```

You can always **test if the solution is the correct** by:

```
// e is an element and e must exist inside the page
document.querySelector( myUniqueQuerySelector(e)) === e && 
document.querySelectorAll( myUniqueQuerySelector(e)).length === 1
```

Comment: really good answer! in the first option, is it possible to make the query shorter if the element has an id or another unique attribute?

Comment: @Giuppox if you have an id, the query selector is `#<idvalue>`, if you have an unique attribute or an attribute with unique value, you could use `tag[attribute='regular-expresion']`. more info here ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector#find_a_specific_element_with_specific_values_of_an_attribute )

Answer (score 0):

I mixed the 2 solutions proposed to have a result readable by humans and which gives the right element if there are several similar siblings:

```js
function elemToSelector(elem) {
  const {
    tagName,
    id,
    className,
    parentNode
  } = elem;

  if (tagName === 'HTML') return 'HTML';

  let str = tagName;

  str += (id !== '') ? `#${id}` : '';

  if (className) {
    const classes = className.split(/\s/);
    for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
      str += `.${classes[i]}`;
    }
  }

  let childIndex = 1;

  for (let e = elem; e.previousElementSibling; e = e.previousElementSibling) {
    childIndex += 1;
  }

  str += `:nth-child(${childIndex})`;

  return `${elemToSelector(parentNode)} > ${str}`;
}
```

Test with:

```js
// Select an element in Elements tab of your navigator Devtools, or replace $0

document.querySelector(elemToSelector($0)) === $0 &&
document.querySelectorAll(elemToSelector($0)).length === 1
```

Which might give you something like, it's a bit longer but it's readable and it always works:

```
HTML > BODY:nth-child(2) > DIV.container:nth-child(2) > DIV.row:nth-child(2) > DIV.col-md-4:nth-child(2) > DIV.sidebar:nth-child(1) > DIV.sidebar-wrapper:nth-child(2) > DIV.my-4:nth-child(1) > H4:nth-child(3)
```

Edit: I just found the package [`unique-selector`](https://github.com/ericclemmons/unique-selector)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
const querySelectorInvers = (elem) => {
      let query = "";
      document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((el) => {
        if (el !== elem) {
          query += ":not(" + el.tagName + ")";
        }
      });
      return query;
    }
```