# Python Selenium: Unable to locate the element by Xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a save button via selenium, however, I am getting the error that it is unable to locate the element.

[this is the html part of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XuJs.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("xxx")

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_id("DivFlashViewerMain_SavePdfButtonIcon")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DivFlashViewerMain_SavePdfButtonIcon"]').click()
```

This is the error I am getting:

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"DivFlashViewerMain_SavePdfButtonIcon"}
>   (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=74.0.3729.6
>   (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows
>   NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `element_to_be_clickable` not just `presence_of_element_located`.

It should look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("xxx")

button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "DivFlashViewerMain_SavePdfButtonIcon")))
button.click()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This should nail the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id="DivFlashViewerMain_SavePdfButtonIcon"]')[0].click()
```

Seems like you are using a lot of functions, example for locating id="". Highly recommend trying css-selectors:
[How to use querySelectorAll only for elements that have a specific attribute set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777684/how-to-use-queryselectorall-only-for-elements-that-have-a-specific-attribute-set/56328426#56328426)

Comment: Using CSS-selectors is highly recommend... yet I think OP's issue is with waiting for `presence_of_element_located` any way +1! ;)